# How to disable or remove Yii2 redactor Image and file button?

Tags: php, yii2, redactor

I am using **Yii2** Redactor from [Here](https://github.com/yiidoc/yii2-redactor). I want to remove `Image and File Upload`.

**view Code :**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'reason')->widget(
\yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::className(), [])

 ?>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to hide the buttons for all instances of Redactor you can add this into the module config

```
'modules' => [
    'redactor' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
        'widgetClientOptions' => [
            'buttonsHide' => ['image','file'],
        ]
    ],
],
```

Otherwise you can add this to the individual call

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'reason')->widget(\yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'buttonsHide' => ['image','file'],
    ]
])?>
```

Comment: Note that hiding this buttons does not disable upload functionality - controller will still handle uploads if it will get valid request. It may be security vulnerability (anyone will be able to upload files to your server).

Comment: @rob006 Do you have any better sollution ?

Answer (score -2):

In this library, you just have to update file i.e. **Redactor.php** at path
**yii2-redactor/widgets/Redactor.php**

Now update method **defaultOptions**.
*Comment or Remove line from 92 to 103*
Here is code of these lines:

```
$this->setOptionsKey('imageUpload', $this->module->imageUploadRoute);
        $this->setOptionsKey('fileUpload', $this->module->fileUploadRoute);
        $this->clientOptions['imageUploadErrorCallback'] = ArrayHelper::getValue($this->clientOptions, 'imageUploadErrorCallback', new JsExpression("function(json){alert(json.error);}"));
        $this->clientOptions['fileUploadErrorCallback'] = ArrayHelper::getValue($this->clientOptions, 'fileUploadErrorCallback', new JsExpression("function(json){alert(json.error);}"));
        if (isset($this->clientOptions['plugins']) && array_search('imagemanager', $this->clientOptions['plugins']) !== false) {
            $this->setOptionsKey('imageManagerJson', $this->module->imageManagerJsonRoute);
        }
        if (isset($this->clientOptions['plugins']) && array_search('filemanager', $this->clientOptions['plugins']) !== false) {
            $this->setOptionsKey('fileManagerJson', $this->module->fileManagerJsonRoute);
        }
```